# manipulating items of a vector in R without using loops

Tags: r

Suppose a vector of integers like this:

```
vect<-c(2,3,4)
```

i want to change this vector to another vector in which all elements are multiplied by 2 and subtracted from 20 .and get result like this:

```
result<-c(16,14,12)
```

in Python, there is a simple method like this:

```
result=[20-(item*2) for item in vect]
```

i know it can be easily done with a loop but i was wondering if there is any similar short method as in python in R? its probably a very basic question but im new to R and could not find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: `result <- 20 - vect * 2`?

Comment: Please read an R tutorial, doesn't matter which one. R works in a vectorized way, and that is explained in every possible tutorial I've ever read, often on page 1.

Comment: @JorisMeys, I'd bet you reccomend "R for Dummies" as your favorite tutorial ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Honestly, "R for Dummies" is especially directed to people that don't want to google their way through learning R and want a handy reference that includes most of the basic stuff. In this case, it would be the perfect tutorial indeed :-) But the free R tutorials and websites like stackoverflow are sufficient for most people willing to put some effort into their learning. Just don't tell anybody ;-)

Comment: @user3015703, Joris is a co-author of "R for Dummies" which is actually a great introduction to R. It's a nice read even for those who are already experienced with the language.

Comment: @user3015703 There's no need to be offended. Actually, you would benefit from a good read through it. The question you asked is comparable to the question "I want to assign a numeric value to a name. In R, I do this as `myname <- 1`. Does anything like this exists in Python?". vectorized calculation are the core of R. If you don't know this, you'll be writing a ton of loops and get utterly frustrated about how "slow" R appears. If you don't want to spend the few bucks on the book, start with "The R Guide" of Owen : http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Owen-TheRGuide.pdf

Comment: @JorisMeys.Thanks. Actually im reading the book "learning statistics with R"  that teaches R really well by far i could do most of statistical analysis using R but it didnt explained vecotrized aspect of R well or maybe it did and i forgot because i dont have good background in computer science!. i started using R just one month ago to complete some statistical part of my doctorate thesis in Genetics which could not be done in Python easily. Thats so nice that there are people like you who are experts and know how to talk properly at the same time! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
vect2 <- 20 - vect * 2
```